# ubuntu サーバーへのリモートログイン

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu 16.04のクライアントとからubuntu 16.04 サーバーへリモートデスクトップで
操作できることは確認しております。

クライアントがremmina または　tightvnc で、サーバー側vino（デスクトップの共有）へ接続できます。ただし、これはサーバー側ですでにログインが終了している場合に限られるようです。

私の環境では、クライアントからリモートでログインしたいのですが、ネット情報によるとubuntu16.04 のunityが対応していないらしく、どうしたものかと悩んでいます。

どなたかリモートログインできる方法をご存じですか。Windows7 64bitからも同様にリモートログイン
したいのですが、こちらも方法をご存知でしたら、お願いします。

ちなみにサーバー側の電源はクライアント（ubuntu）からwakeonlanで投入できることは確認しています。

Answer (score 1):

試してませんが XDMCPで接続すればどうでしょう。

サーバー側で`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`に次の設定を追記します。

```
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
```

lightdm を再起動します。

```
systemctl restart lightdm
```

※ログイン中のセッションが切れますので作業中のプロセスが合ったら事前に終了してください

クライアント側はRemmina、Windowsの場合は Xmingを使って接続します。